# Geodatabase performance and Archiving

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase

We have SDE (10.3) running on SQL Server (SQL Server 2012 on Windows Server 2012 R2)

Over time we've noticed our GIS performance degrade, and can have good days and bad days.  We run versioned editing, replication, have geometric and network datasets, and have archiving enabled.  We run regular (several times a day) compresses to keep things running smoothly.

My question is whether having archiving enabled on our heavily edited datasets would have a noticible effect on performance?  We are not in a position to test this, so wonder if anyone else has experience with testing the performance of archiving heavily edited data.  Some of our feature classes could have anywhere from 100 to 10,000 edited records in a day.

We've had our geodatabase with all our different types of datasets and functions running for a number of years, and it's only since we migrated from arcsde 9.3 to 10.3 (about a year ago) that we've noticed the significant performance issues.

Comment: The obvious answer is "Yes, enabling archiving can have an impact on performance", but the exact impact is very dependent on local factors, and therefore doesn't lend itself to "we found this, so you can do it too" solutions.

Comment: @Vince - without a doubt it'll have an impact, I'm rather trying to find whether it's likely to have a significant impact compared to other causes.  Someone may have investigated this for themselves, and I'm interested in feedback on this.  It's very hard to test heavy edits on anything other than production data, and we don't (at this stage) want to remove the Archive (due to not being able to re-link the archive table later)

Comment: I think you're overestimating the number of organizations that have anything like your environment.  This is really a conversation to be having with Esri.

Comment: possibly, but all it takes is one, right?

Comment: we've talked with our local support (not in US so can't use Esri) and they haven't offered much help, so thought I'd come here to ask people in the real world

Comment: No, you just have to get your distributor (or vertical market manager) to reach back to Redlands.  This is too complex to handle via GIS SE.  No one here is going to give you a hundred hours of consulting time.

Comment: http://www.blairservices.net/case-studies/arcgis-archiving-deep-dive-part-1/